# Pass from Model to BLL to DAL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have this class in Model

```
   public class AssignStudentDetails
   {
     public string StudentName { get; set; }
     public string TeacherName { get; set; }
   }
```

This is my BLL layer, I want add Addstudentdetails to list and then pass it to DAL layer

```
   public void AddStudentsList(AssignStudentDetails AddStudentDetails) 
   {
      //code how to add addstudentdetails and pass to DAL 
   }


    public void AddStudentDAL(//what i have to pass here?)
    { 
      //my sql connection i will write here
    }
```

Please let me know how to do it

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? What are you trying to achieve and what problems you've encountered so far?

Comment: I have written SQL connection for inserting studentname and teachername, now i want to pass the data from that Assignstudent details class to BLL layer and from BLL to DAL function i have to pass values

Answer (score 0):

Change method return type from void to AssignStudentDetails in BLL:

```
public AssignStudentDetails AddStudentsList(AssignStudentDetails AddStudentDetails) 
{
  //code how to add addstudentdetails and pass to DAL 
  AssignStudentDetails assgnStdDet = new AssignStudentDetails ()
  {
     AssignStudentDetailsProperty = AddStudentDetails.CorrespondingProperty
     //rest of properties
  }
  return assgnStdDet; 
}
```

Then call BLL method in DAL:

```
public void AddStudentDAL(AssignStudentDetails AddStudentDetails)
{ 
  //my sql connection i will write here
  AssignStudentDetails assgnStdDet = AddStudentsList(AddStudentDetails);
  YourDBContext.AssignStudentDetailsDBSet.Add(assgnStdDet);
  YourDBContext.SaveChanges();
}
```